# What happens when you have the same pair and same kicker

Tags: texas-hold-em

What happens in Texas Holdem when
You have the same pair as another person
And you also have the same kicker
Is it split pot or then do you go to the next Highest kicker?

For example: (suits irrelevant)
Frank A,Q
Bill A,7

Cards 2,2,6,5,4

Franks best: 2, 2, A, Q, 6.
Bill best: 2, 2, A, 7, 6.

Answer (score 1):

You keep iterating but only taking the 5 best cards into account (which means up to 3 kickers in your example wit the pair). So in your example Frank wins while if they would hold A8 and A7 on a 22QJ3 board (no flush), it would be a split (both play a pair of deuces with AQJ as kickers).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you keep iterating through hands (their "best five cards") until someone has a better card. If not, this is split pot.

In you example, Frank wins with his Q.

Comment: No! No! Poker hands have exactly, precisely, five cards. No more, no fewer. If you "keep iterating though the hand" as you put it, and the player's 6th or 7th cards differ, they are irrelevant.

Comment: By the hand I mean "best five cards" for the two players. Because their "best five cards" are their hands. I would never imagine that someone playing poker can understand it any other way...

Comment: You'd be surprized. The question gets asked about once a week, and people want to play kickers with their straights too.

Comment: Ok, why not. But to get down votes just because I didn't specify the obvious is a bit harsh...

Comment: I disagree, and I am keeping my downvote in place, because I think the phase `their "best five cards" obviously` is condescending to new players who don't understand this rule yet, almost certainly including the OP. Most players begin with a simple hand chart that doesn't mention the term "kicker" anywhere on it and many learn the hard way that a pair of twos is worse than a pair of threes, because these charts don't even make that clear.

Comment: I have removed "obviously", you are right.